# VirtualBox P2V Win7 FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk2vhd

There are 3 other topics with this title. Only 1 has an answer, it doesn't help in my situation. I have gone from physical 2 virtual VHD once before, 10 years ago. I didn't have any problems, so I am not an expert in this process and don't understand anything but the basic process as outlined below.

I had an older Dell Optiplex desktop with Intel i3 core processor running Win7 on a 1TB SATA hard drive. The motherboard overheated and fried.

Built a new desktop with Ryzen 5 5600G processor and 2TB SSD system disk running Win11 Home.

I put the old Win7 OS hard drive into the SATA bay in the new computer and I can mount it and see all the files there just fine.

In Windows Disk Management, that drive shows with 3 partitions as such.
[Disk 1 in Windows Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yepc4.png)

- 39 MB Healthy (OEM Partition)
- Recovery (E:) 13.78 GB NTFS Healthy (Primary Partition)
- OS (F:) 917.69 GB NTFS Healthy (Primary Parition)

I use Windows Disk2VHD to create the VHD drive. I select the last 2 partitions (E: and F: drives) as the first partition does not show as an option. I did not select/check any of the 3 options in the upper right. I clicked on Create and it created the VHD file in 45 minutes.
[Disk2vhd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fMZO.png)

Next, in Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager (Version 6.1.32 r149290 (Qt5.6.2)), I create the virtual machine and select the VHD created above.
[VirtualBox VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE1HB.png)

- 8192 MB Ram
- 128 MB video memory

When I **Start** the VM, I immediately get the **FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE** message.

I have spent a couple weeks on this problem and I am not getting anywhere.

The goal is obviously to be able to boot that Win7 OS, as I have some legacy products on there that are no longer available anywhere. I still need them.

Any other way to get from my starting point (a seemingly good Win7 disk drive that used to boot in my older Dell desktop) to a bootable VM?

I have looked into other P2V (physical 2 virtual) software other than Disk2VHD, but I can't remember everything I tried and the results (it's been a long two weeks). VMWare Converter is no longer available. So that is out.

For this INT18 error, some searches mention setting the "Enable EFI" option on your VM and that will cause it to boot into System Repair mode and fix this error. That doesn't happen for me, it boots into a "Shell>" prompt that I have no idea what to do with.

Some sites mention selecting the Disk2VHD option for "Prepare for use in Virtual PC", that didn't work. It still produces the INT18 error.

Since I have Win11 *Home* I don't have Hyper-V capability on this machine. But would gladly purchase the upgrade to Pro if folks believe that Hyper-V will not have any problems.

Comment: Drivers may be an issue.  VMware Vcenter Converter is still available from VMware so you may wish to investigate that.  Also, if you have the Legacy software for reinstalling, also consider making a Windows 7 machine from the Windows 7 DVD and install the legacy software in that.

Comment: The VMware website says it stopped providing Converter 3-4 years ago. An extensive search by me couldn't find otherwise. If you know if a link, I would love to try it. No, I do not have the legacy software; hence the need to boot this drive. Thx.

Comment: Try this link:    https://www.vmware.com/ca/support/download-converter.html

Comment: Thx John. But, go ahead and try the Download link. It doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are correct about the VMware Site. Try this site for Vcenter V6   ....  https://www.filehorse.com/download-vmware-vcenter-converter/download/   ...  A download started for me.

Comment: Ok - downloaded and installed VMware vCenter Converter Standalone v6.2. Cannot figure out how to convert a raw disk to a VHD (or other format). Two options are 1) Convert machine and 2) Configure machine. Neither of which ask for a drive like disk2vhd. Really stuck here.

Comment: Can you convert to VMDK and try a trial version of VMware Workstation?

Comment: How would I go about creating a VMDK?

Comment: VMware Converter should provide an option to make a VMDK file (VMware OS file ) from the physical machine.

Comment: Definitely needing instructions here. It has 2 options as shown above. As my post above states, I have an old OS hard drive that used to boot Win7 on an old machine wherein the motherboard died. Now I have that drive in a new machine. Mounted and accessible. How do I create any type of virtual drive file using vConverter? I can't find it.

Comment: You need a computer to run converter, old disk in a carrier and enough space in the computer to take the VMDK (could be 100 GB and possibly more).

Comment: HI John. I have a computer running Win11. With the old Win7 disk attached inside. This site seems to indicate that vConverter cannot convert a standalone hard disk: https://www.altaro.com/vmware/vmware-converter-p2v/ - it seems to indicate what I have found by running vConverter. I don't see any way to convert a hard disk like I can with disk2vhd utility.

Comment: Where I have seen Converter work is by installing it on the system to be converted. I realize you cannot do this (I was hoping you could) but the error above I think is true. It is probably related to drivers on the system to be converted.